# Android music player fc and error opening trace file

Tags: java, android, media-player, audio-player, android-music-player

Ive recently been building a music app and ive been using some source code and customizing it to my own spec. I finish editing and debug and it suspends at launch.

Debug:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2306    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2356 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 150    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1244  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5195    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 795  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 562 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

[Logcat Log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21682671/log2.txt) (cant seem to get it to show on here)

Can someone take a look at my code and tell me where ive gone wrong?

Here's my project class code:

```
package com.timmo.tampmusicplayer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NowPlaying extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
// Media Player
private MediaPlayer mp;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nowplaying);

    // All player buttons
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bplay);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bnext);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bprevious);
    btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bLibrary);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.brepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bshuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtimecurrent);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtimetotal);

    // Mediaplayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

    // Getting all songs list
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    // By default play first song
    playSong(0);

    /**
     * Play button click event plays a song and changes button to pause
     * image pauses a song and changes button to play image
     * */
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
            } else {
                // Resume song
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Forward button click event Forwards song specified seconds
     * */
    btnNext.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()) {
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            } else {
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    /**
     * Backward button click event Backward song to specified seconds
     * */
    btnPrevious.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
            if (currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0) {
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            } else {
                // backward to starting position
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            return true;

        }
    });

    /**
     * Next button click event Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex +
     * 1
     * */
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check if next song is there or not
            if (currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)) {
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            } else {
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Back button click event Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
     * */
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (currentSongIndex > 0) {
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            } else {
                // play last song
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Repeat button Enables repeat flag to true
     * */
    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (isRepeat) {
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.norepeat);
            } else {
                // make repeat to true
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.repeat);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.noshuffle);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Shuffle button Enables shuffle flag to true
     * */
    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (isShuffle) {
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.noshuffle);
            } else {
                // make repeat to true
                isShuffle = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.noshuffle);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.norepeat);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Play list click event Launches list activity
     * which displays list of songs
     * */
    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Library.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view and play the song
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        // play selected song
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * 
 * @param songIndex
 *            - index of song
 * */
public void playSong(int songIndex) {
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        // Displaying Total Duration time
        songTotalDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        // Displaying time completed playing
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        // Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

/**
 * 
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

/**
 * On Song Playing completed if repeat is ON play same song again if shuffle
 * is ON play random song
 * */
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // check for repeat is ON or OFF
    if (isRepeat) {
        // repeat is on play same song again
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if (isShuffle) {
        // shuffle is on - play a random song
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else {
        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if (currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)) {
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        } else {
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
}

}
```

Library.java

```
package com.timmo.tampmusicplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Library extends ListActivity {
// Songs list
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();
    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting listitem index
            int songIndex = position;

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NowPlaying.class);
            // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
            setResult(100, in);
            // Closing PlayListView
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Anything is great as long as you make sure you make sense thanks

logcat

```
3-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.timmo.tampmusicplayer/com.timmo.tampmusicplayer.NowPlaying}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at com.timmo.tampmusicplayer.NowPlaying.onCreate(NowPlaying.java:54)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):    ... 11 more
```

---

Comment: Are you running it from Eclipse? Seems to me that it's actually stopping execution because of a Runtime Exception (might be a Null Pointer Exception or anything derived from a Runtime Exception) and you need to let it continue in its execution so it shows you a logcat that actually contains an error...

Comment: Any idea how I go about doing that?

Comment: In your Debug view press the red disconnect button.

Comment: You should take the time to condense your code into only the most relevant parts.

Comment: Ive pressed the terminate and it showed the errors in Logcat. Can someone take a look at my updated link?

Comment: You need to post your layout xml as well, to get a bit more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting one object into the wrong type.

```
03-22 23:53:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(25591):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.timmo.tampmusicplayer/com.timmo.tampmusicplayer.NowPlaying}:
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to 
android.widget.ImageButton
```

I'll elaborate: you have a Button in your layout which you're attempting to access as an ImageButton.

Comment: You can: a.) mark this question as resolved and post a new one (which I reccommend for clarity) or b.) expand this one (which might actually muddle the question)

Comment: OK will do. Here's some reputation